# Django website accessible to others just for testing

Tags: django, localhost, web-hosting, mezzanine

Right now the website is running locally and I'm still working on it.
While doing this I also have to make it visible to a specific group of users as I need their feedback in order to add/change features, etc.

I've tried to find a free web hosting without any luck (see dependencies).
I was thinking to create a VPN but then I will have to use my PC as a host for a virtual machine which is by far not what I'm looking for.

Therefore, my questions are:
 1. Which is the best way to achieve this (website visibility **for TESTING**) fast and easy?
 2. If a dedicated web host is the best solution, please point me to an easy-to-use and cheap one. What I've tried so far: [elastichosts](http://www.elastichosts.com/), [alwasydata](https://www.alwaysdata.com/), [stackable](http://stackable.com/), [1FreeHosting](http://1FreeHosting.com) and probably others I don't remember right now. For a reason or another I couldn't use none of the above.

Another aspect to be considered: I want this only for **simple testing** and I **don't need a lot of server resources**. Also the **traffic will be very low** as there are only 5 testers. That's why I wouldn't pay too much for it. I will probably need this temporary web hosting for 2-3 months.

Dependencies:
 - as the website uses [mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org), for the moment I only need [mezzanine's dependencies](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/overview.html#dependencies).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always just setup port forwarding on your router. This would allow your testers direct access to your app. Though this might give your PC more exposure than you want.

Heroku has a free tier.

In your non free options, an instance at linode costs $20/month, but requires some setup. Rackspace has similar options in their cloud servers line. Both are no contract servers.

Answer (score 0):

[My blogpost covers gracefully deploying a Mezzanine site.](http://bscientific.org/blog/mezzanine-fabric-git-vagrant-joy/) The monthly hosting cost is nothing compared to the cost of a slow, painful deployment process.

An EC2 micro-instance right now costs as little as ~US$3.50/month. I create and destroy staging servers on EC2 servers for testing and sharing with others.